# C# searching the Inbox for specific subjects emails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook

I am trying to search for specific emails that have a particulary subject.

```
Outlook.Folder inbox = new Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Outlook.Items items = inbox.Items;
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;
            object folderItem;
            string subjectName = string.Empty;
            string filter = "[Subject] > 's' And [Subject] <'u'";
            folderItem = items.Find(filter);
            while (folderItem != null)
            {
                mailItem = folderItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                if (mailItem != null)
                {
                    subjectName += "\n" + mailItem.Subject;
                }
                folderItem = items.FindNext();

            }
            subjectName = "The follow e-mail messages were found: " + subjectName;
            MessageBox.Show(subjectName);
```

I am getting an error :
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0426  The type name 'ActiveExplorer' does not exist in the type 'Application'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `Application` instance first if you develop a standalone application where Outlook is automated or use the built-in property if you develop a VSTO based add-in instead of the following code:

```
Outlook.Folder inbox = new Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

A standalone application should create a new Outlook instance:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Explorer explorer = app.ActiveExplorer();
Outlook.Namespace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.Folder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

In case of VSTO add-in you can use the `Application` property of the `ThisAddin` class:

```
Outlook.Explorer explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();
Outlook.Namespace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.Folder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

You can read more about the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Find)/[FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.FindNext) or [Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict) methods of the `Items` class in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) method helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the Filtering article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the Search class.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are even accessing `ActiveExplorer` - you are not using it, and if Outlook was not running prior, there won't be any open explorers (and inspectors), so `ActiveExplorer` will return null anyway.

Also keep in mind that `Application.Session` will be null unless Outlook is already running - you need to log in first.

Thirdly, you are not calling a constructor - that would be `new Outlook.Application().Blah` (note `()`).

Change your code to

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Namespace session = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
session.Logon();
Outlook.Folder inbox = session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

Comment: Meanwhile I had modified it in the way that you answered. I have a problema accesing informations from the email itself, I can just fine creat folders in inbox, counting the email from inbox, but cant acces ```foreach(Outlook.MailItem item in mails)    {  string subj = item.Subject;}``` inside foreach(...) I get an exception, I have the isssue in another quesstion if you wana take a look. Thank!

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!